# 2 VPN connections, But DNS of the second one is not reachable

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, internal-dns

I have to use 2 VPNs to be able to connect the Network of my Work. If i use the OpenVPN (my work vpn) i can resolve the DNS normaly. If i connect another vpn before i connect the OpenVPN, i can reach the servers of my work just over IP Adresses. I'm aware that the DNS server of the second VPN (OpenVPN) has to get somehow configured on my local windows 10 machine to be reachable through those 3 different Networks (Local over WLAN, First VPN, OpenVPN).
Can someone help me with my issue?
those are the configurations of the 3 Networks:

```
first VPN: 
Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet 3:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : ExpressVPN TAP Adapter
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-66-FC-85-A0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.115.0.210(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 14. November 2020 21:17:13
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Sonntag, 14. November 2021 21:17:13
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.115.0.209
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.115.0.1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

OpenVPN Network:
       
Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: company.webadress.com
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-cc-cc
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.8.28(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Sonntag, 15. November 2020 15:51:31
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Montag, 15. November 2021 15:51:31
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.8.254
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.51
                                       10.0.0.52
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert


WLAN Network:
Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: fritz.box
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : E4-70-B8-FF-A6-9F
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.48(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 14. November 2020 21:04:19
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Dienstag, 24. November 2020 21:16:55
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.27.1
                                       192.168.178.1
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
```

Comment: You need to use 2 VPN's to connect to your work network? That doesn't make much sense. Why do you have 2 VPN connections for work?

Comment: bacause am not using it always from same place. in some countries the normal ports of vpns are blocked and the paid VPN can overcome this block.